# vue-18n - how to force reload in computed function when changing language

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, internationalization

I am using vue-i18n but I also have some content which is stored in database. I would like my text to be updated when the user changes the language.
I am using laravel and vuejs2.
Thanks in advance, I am not super familiar with vuejs yet. I hope it's clear enough.

in ContenuComponent.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        {{$i18n.locale}}                                      <== this changes well
        <div v-html="textcontent"></div>
        <div v-html="textcontent($i18n.locale)"></div>        <== this won't work, I am wondering how to put params here (more like a general quetsion)
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name:'contenu',
    props: {
      content: {
          type: String,
          default: '<div></div>'
      }
    },
    computed: {
        textcontent: function () {
            console.log(navigator.language);            <== this gives me the language as well, so i could use it if I can make it reload
            var parsed = JSON.parse(this.content);
            parsed.forEach(element => {
                if(navigator.language == element['lang']){
                    return element['text'];
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

in ContentController

```
public function getcontent(){
        $content = DB::connection('mysql')->select( DB::connection('mysql')->raw("
            SELECT text, lang from content
            "));
        return view('myvue', ['content' => json_encode($content)]);
    }
```

in content.blade.php

```
<div id="app">
    <contenu content="{{ $content }}"></contenu>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You SHOULD NOT pass parameters to computed props! They are not methods and you should create method instead:

```
methods: {
    textcontent () {
        var parsed = JSON.parse(this.content)
        parsed.forEach(element => {
            if (navigator.language == element['lang']){
                return element['text']
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Also you should consider ES6 syntax:

```
methods: {
    textcontent () {
        var parsed = JSON.parse(this.content)
        const content = parsed.find(element => navigator.language == element['lang'])

        return content['text']
    }
}
```

Much cleaner!

Please make sure to read about computed props and how they are different than methods or watchers: [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Comment: Thanks you so much for your answer Ignas! And thanks for the tips. Indeed, that explains why I couldn't get the text to change when "navigator.language" was changing:

A computed property will only re-evaluate when some of its reactive dependencies have changed. This means as long as message has not changed, multiple access to the reversedMessage computed property will immediately return the previously computed result without having to run the function again.